# Make edit descriptions editable by moderators

Tags: feature-request, edit-summary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow mods to edit revision comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59597/allow-mods-to-edit-revision-comments)

Here's why:

- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4149530/revisions
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5164047/revisions
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3887095/revisions

Comment: Hehe, I say leave it.  They are funny.

Comment: And, now that I have the right tag to work from - [here's another incident that spawned a similar sentiment for allowing some kind of monitoring](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59564/complaint-against-user-who-edited-my-post). And, consequently, [the same sentiment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59597/allow-mods-to-edit-revision-comments). Poke to @Pop. ♪

Comment: @jjnguy It's just mindless ranting in edit comments. Boring. (And rather over-the-top considering how minor the edits actually are.)

Comment: @Anna, I guess I think it's funny because he decided to mindlessly rant in a venue that is most likely to be hidden from view.

Answer (score 5):

Seems like those edits are all one person using the same foul languages. If this gets out of hand, it could make SE NSFW, which is bad for SE.

I'd just warn the user.

That said, this is a good idea, but not necessarily for the reasons you suggest.