# Edit Summary edits aren't reflected on user's activity page

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, recent-activity, edit-summary

User X recently edited their post (which has been closed) and wrote in the edit summary something rude (not *too* rude, but not nice) about those who closed the post. So I (a mod on that site) simply [edited it out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273359/166155).

However, if you go to User X's activity page under revisions, the rude edit summary persists and anyone can see it.

This seems like a bug. The whole point of editing it out is so it's gone.

Comment: I don't think you can leave it blank. Can you try again, this time putting something else?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I didn't leave it blank. Just removed the rude part.

Comment: Oh. So looks like the summary shown in the recent activity is static, not taken from the same place as revisions. Bug indeed, hopefully will be fixed soon.

Comment: When you don't link to the post in question, people like me with way too much morbid curiosity have to waste time hunting it down. "thick headed people" was disappointingly tame ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We used to just look at the actual revision and the original comment that was left with it rather than checking for any subsequent changes to it.

I pushed a fix that accounts for the summary edits, and it will go live in the next build (rev 2016.8.24.4918 on MSE/MSO, rev 2016.8.24.3922 elsewhere).